# TcpClient/NetworkStream not detecting disconnection

Tags: tcp, unity-game-engine, tcpclient, networkstream

I created a simple persistent socket connection for our game using `TcpClient` and `NetworkStream`. There's no problem connecting, sending messages, and disconnecting normally (quitting app/server shuts down/etc).

However, I'm having some problems where, in certain cases, the client isn't detecting a disconnection from the server. The easiest way I have of testing this is to pull out the network cable on the wifi box, or set the phone to airplane mode, but it's happened in the middle of a game on what should otherwise be a stable wifi.

Going through the docs for `NetworkStream` etc, it says that the only way to detect a disconnection is to try to write to the socket. Fair enough, except, when I try, the write passes as if nothing is wrong. I can write multiple messages like this, and everything seems fine. It's only when I plug the cable back in that it sees that it's disconnected (all messages are buffered?).

The `TcpClient` is set to `NoDelay`, and there's a `Flush()` called after every write anyway.

What I've tried:

- Writing a message to the `NetworkStream` - no joy
- `CanWrite`, `Connected`, etc all return true
- `TcpClient.Client.Poll( 1000, SelectMode.SelectWrite );` - returns true
- `TcpClient.Client.Poll( 1000, SelectMode.SelectRead ) && TcpClient.Client.Available == 0` - returns true
- `TcpClient.Client.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.Peek) == 0` - when connected, blocks for about 10-20s, then returns true. When no server, blocks forever(?)
- `NetworkStream.Write()` - doesn't throw an error
- `NetworkStream.BeginWrite()` - doesn't throw an error (not even when calling `EndWrite()`)
- Setting a `WriteTimeout` - had no effect
- Having a specific time where we haven't received a message from the server (normally there's a keep-alive) - I had this, but removed it, as we were getting a lot of false-positives due to lag etc (some clients would see between 10-20s of lag)

So am I doing something wrong here? Is there any way to get the `NetworkStream` to throw an error (like it should) when writing to a socket that should be disconnected?

I've no problem with a keep-alive (the default case is the server will notify the client that it hasn't received anything in a while, and the client will send a heartbeat), but at the minute, according to the `NetworkStream` everything's hunky-dory.

It's for a game, so ideally the detection should be quick enough (as the user can still move through the game until they need to make a server call, some of which will block the UI, so the game seems broken).

I'm using Unity, so it's .Net 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is to pull out the network cable on the wifi box

That's a good test. If you do that the remote party is not notified. How could it possibly find out? It can't.

> when I try, the write passes as if nothing is wrong

Writes can (and are) buffered. They eventually enter a block hole... No reply comes back. The only way to detect this is a timeout.

> So am I doing something wrong here?

You have tried a lot of things but fundamentally you cannot find out about disconnects if no reply comes back telling you that. Use a timeout.

Comment: Thanks - pulling the network cable out is the only was I can test it - the actual bug is happening in production code while users are supposedly connected to stable wifi. And by timeout, you mean on the client, if they haven't received a message in X time, right?

Comment: "stable wifi" I have never seen such a thing :) It doesn't matter, this problem can happen for any number of reasons. You must be able to deal with it.; Regarding timeout: It has to be on the side that wants to detect connection loss. Seems obvious... did I understand your question right?

Comment: ok, I think I get it - the writes are getting buffered, so for the client, everything is fine. And, yes for the timeout - I'm just used to people talking about a server side timeout, so I wanted to clarify

Comment: Last question before I accept the answer: is there a way to set the max "buffer" time for a socket. I.e. if it's been buffered X seconds without being sent, then disconnect? Would that just be covered by the custom client-side timeout?

Comment: Nagling is what causes most buffering on the sending host. Maybe you can change the nagling time (default: 200ms). This will not help much because the data *is* sent successfully. It is just not received. The TCP stack cannot do much here. Whether the stack implements the timeout or your code does it does not change anything in principle. The only thing that the TCP stack can do is perform retransmits but this won't save you.