# TcpListener reading request returning -1

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I'm using `TcpListener` like this:

```
TcpListener _listener;

public void Start()
{
    _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8000);
    _listener.Start();
    _listener.BeginAcceptSocket(this.HandleAcceptTcpClient, _listener);
}

private void HandleAcceptTcpClient(IAsyncResult result)
{
    TcpClient client = _listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);
    _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAcceptTcpClient, _listener);

    Console.WriteLine("Accepting connection...");

    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        char c;
        while ((c = (char)reader.Read()) != 0)
        {
            Console.Write(c);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

When I make a request to `localhost:8000` in Chrome, I the following response in the console (the `?`'s are endless):

[image]

And when I change the code inside `HandleAcceptTcpClient` to this (changed it to print ints instead of chars):

```
private void HandleAcceptTcpClient(IAsyncResult result)
{
    TcpClient client = _listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);
    _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(HandleAcceptTcpClient, _listener);

    Console.WriteLine("Accepting connection...");

    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        // the changes are on the next 5 lines
        int i;
        while ((i = reader.Read()) != 0)
        {
            Console.Write(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

I get the following:

[image]

So basically, the browser seems to be making another request and sending only `-1`; also, doing `reader.ReadToEnd()` just hangs, meaning it's endless.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is purpose of writing all of these codes? what do you *really* want to do?

Comment: @Eser I'm just trying to read the data sent to the TcpListener but after the actual request I'm getting a new request which sends `-1` endlessly

Comment: I asked in the context of [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Your`s connection probably closed, try to detect disconnection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31322716/tcpclient-networkstream-not-detecting-disconnection

Comment: @gabba If the connection were closed, the StreamReader would throw an exception instead of doing this weird behaviour

Comment: Browser wait an answer, and you trying to read something, timeout occurs for read and reader returns -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not Chrome sending another request. It seems to be [Stream.ReadByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readbyte(v=vs.110).aspx) method that returns -1 since it reaches end of the stream.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readbyte(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Return Value: The unsigned byte cast to an Int32, or
>   -1 if at the end of the stream.

So the output makes sense if StreamReader uses the Stream.ReadByte method of the input stream to read data from it.